# Regex - How to exclude matches without look-behind?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to scan all attributes from a database, searching for specific patterns and ignoring similar ones that I know should not match but I'm having some problems as in the below example:

Let's say I'm trying to find Customer Registration Numbers and one of my patterns is this:
`.*CRN.*`
Then I'm ignoring everything that are not CRNs (like currency and country name) like this:
`(CRN)(?!CY|AME)`
So far everything is working fine as look ahead is included in Javascript

The next step is to exclude things like SCRN (screen) for example but look behind `(?<!S)(CRN)(?!CY|AME)` doesn't work.

Is there any alternative?

Example inputs:
CREDIT_CARD
DISCARD
CARDINALITY
CARDNO

My Regex `(?!.*DISCARD.*|.*CARDINALITY.*).*CARD.*`

CARDINALITY was removed but DISCARD still being considered :(

Comment: Also, if you are using a SQL database, please tell us which _version_ you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.).

Comment: Not using it on a database. It is a javascript that iterates a data dictionary in a flat file.

Comment: I really appreciate the help but none of these patterns are removing the match with the word "DISCARD" from the example. The other post is referring to the negative look-ahead which I'm using to exclude strings after CARD like CARDINALITY but not before like DISCARD. So the problem is still there :(

Comment: You just miss a `^` at the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex that you want is:

`(?!\b(?:CARDINALITY|DISCARD)\b)(\b\w*CARD\w*\b)`

It is important that you are testing the negative lookahead against the entire word and thus we are trying to match `(\b\w*CARD\w*\b)` rather than just `CARD`. The problem with the following regex:

`(?!(?:CARDINALITY|DISCARD))CARD`

is that with the case of DISCARD, when the scan is at the character position where `CARD` begins, we are past `DIS` and you would need a negative lookbehind condition to eliminate DISCARD from consideration. But when we are trying to match the complete word as we are in the regex I propose, we are still at the start of the word when we are applying the negative lookahead conditions.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7CeW3s/1) (click on "RUN TESTS")

Comment: Awesome, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I should have added \b to the negative lookahead also.